# Groupby Yearly Crop Sequences to retrieve count and sum of acres

Tags: python, pandas

Still new to pandas but hungry to learn. I have crop sequences for roughly 8000 agricultural fields describing what crops where present during each year. I also have a master crop list of every possible crop observed for all years of data.

For each 'CropSeq[YR]', I would like to get the frequency of unique crops and then determine the total acreage (sum of 'Acres') associated with a unique crop type.

A dummy example of the crop sequence data:

```
FieldID   Acres    CropSeq04    CropSeq05   CropSeq06
1          20        Barley      Alfalfa      Rye
2          30        Barley        Rye        Rye
3          45       Lettuce      Alfalfa     Beets
4          10         Hay        Alfalfa      Rye
5          15       Alfalfa       Beets      Beets
```

What I envision the output will be:

```
Crops04 Freq04  Acre04    Crops05   Freq05  Acre05    Crops06   Freq06  Acre06
Alfalfa   1       15      Alfalfa     3       75      Beets       2      60
Barley    2       50      Beets       1       15      Rye         3      60
Hay       1       10      Rye         1       30            
Lettuce   1       45
```

With the counts and sums of acres per crop type, I would like to add the values to my 'master' sequence list, ensuring that row values match. NA values or blanks are anticipated as every year does not always contain every possible type of crop. An example of the master sequence list:

```
MasterCropList  |  Crops04  Freq04  Acre04  |  Crops05  Freq05  Acre05  |  Crops06  Freq06  Acre06
Alfalfa         |  Alfalfa    1       15    |  Alfalfa    3       75    |       
Barley          |  Barley     2       50    |                           |
Beets           |                           |  Beets      1       15    |  Beets      2      60
Hay             |  Hay        1       10    |                           |
Rye             |                           |  Rye        1       30    |  Rye        3      60
Lettuce         |  Lettuce    1       45    |                           |
```

I have been able to get the frequencies of unique crops and separately sum the acres of a specific crop type for a single year. However, doing both at the same time escapes me.

Example of acres summed and sorted:

```
# Sums Acres per crop sequence
year04 = cropdf.groupby('Crop04', as_index=False)['Acres'].sum()
year04.sort_values(by=['Acres'], ascending=False)
```

I am continuing to explore how combine the results to the master crop list based on shared values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
new_df= ( 
       pd.concat([( group.add_suffix(i[-2:])
                         .rename(columns={'Crops':i})
                         .reset_index(drop=True) )

        for i,group in ( df.melt(['FieldID','Acres'],
                                 var_name='Seq',
                                 value_name='Crops')

                           .groupby(['Seq','Crops'])
                           .Acres
                           .agg(Freq='size',Acre='sum')
                           .unstack('Seq')
                           .reindex(index=df_master['MasterCropList']) 
                           .stack(dropna=False)
                           .swaplevel()
                           .sort_index()
                           .rename_axis(index=['Seq','Crops'])
                           .reset_index('Crops')
                           .assign(Crops=lambda x: x.Crops.where(x.Freq.notnull()))
                           .groupby(level=0) )],axis=1,sort=True)
)
df_master=( pd.concat([df_master.sort_values('MasterCropList')
                              .reset_index(drop=True),new_df],axis=1)
              .fillna('') )
print(df_master)
```

**Output**

```
  MasterCropList  Crops04 Freq04 Acre04  Crops05 Freq05 Acre05 Crops06 Freq06  \
0        Alfalfa  Alfalfa      1     15  Alfalfa      3     75                  
1         Barley   Barley      2     50                                         
2          Beets                           Beets      1     15   Beets      2   
3            Hay      Hay      1     10                                         
4        Lettuce  Lettuce      1     45                                         
5            Rye                             Rye      1     30     Rye      3   

  Acre06  
0         
1         
2     60  
3         
4         
5     60
```

---

**Initial df_master**

```
print(df_master)
  MasterCropList
0        Alfalfa
1         Barley
2          Beets
3            Hay
4            Rye
5        Lettuce
```

---

- if all `MasterCropList` values ​​are in at least one column of `df1` **then `reindex` is not necessary and `rename_axis` is not**.
- Keep in mind that this solution is flexible and works with many CropSeq columns. Note that if the number of columns exceeds the value 99 then you must modify: `.add_suffix(i[-n:]`.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I did encounter an error at `.agg(Freq='size',Acre='sum')` . I received the following error: `TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_or_funcs'`. After some trial and error I discovered that `.agg({'Freq' : ['size'], 'Acre' : ['sum']})` gets the job done despite being yelled at because using aggregation with a dictionary on a series will be deprecated. I enjoyed breaking your code down. I had no idea .melt() was a thing.

Comment: I am glad to help:), try: `.agg(Freq=('Acres','size'),Acre=('Acres','sum'))`. are you using `.....acres.agg`?

Comment: Correct, I'm using ...`.Acres.agg()`. I tried your suggestion and am still getting the error for a missing positional argument. I really appreciate the help, hats off to you!